# To find out $H_1(CX,X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology

In the exercise of chapter 5 problem 21 in Rotman, he asks if $X$ is a topological space with 5 path components what is $H_1(CX,X)$, where $CX$ is the cone of X ?

I am generalising it to $n$ components and giving it a try:

We have an exact sequence for reduced Homology groups

$...\rightarrow \tilde { H}_1(X)\rightarrow \tilde H_1(CX) \rightarrow H_1(CX,X) \rightarrow \tilde H_0(X) \rightarrow \tilde H_0(CX) \rightarrow H_0(CX,X) \rightarrow 0 $ 
 Since, $CX $ is contractible $\tilde H_1(CX)= H_1(CX)=0$ And since $CX$ is path connected, $\tilde H_0(CX)=0$ and $\tilde H_0(X)= \mathbb {Z}^{\oplus n-1}$

So, from the exact sequence we conclude $H_1(CX,X)=  \mathbb {Z}^{\oplus n-1}$ .

Am I correct?

Is there any alternative way to see it?

Comment: One slight variant is to note that this relative homology is the reduced homology of the suspension, and then to calculate the homology of the suspension. This is largely the same though because of how one proves the suspension isomorphism.

Comment: Yeah I encountered this statement but I don't know the details of that. Is my approach to this problem ok?

Comment: Your proof is correct and it is essentially how you prove the suspension isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for confirming